# ModelState.isValid() is always false during Signup

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

So, I have been creating login and signup method and it is using the IdentityDbContext which takes a model which inherits IdentityUser. Now my Signup model does not have any database attributes or annotations and it's basically a ViewModel class. Here is the code for the model class.

```cs
public class Signup
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your email address!")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid registered email address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your first name!")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your last name!")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please create or enter your password")]
    [Compare("ConfirmPassword", ErrorMessage = "Your password did not match. Please try again!")]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please confirm your password")]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your date of birth")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your mobile number!")]
    [Display(Name = "Mobile Number")]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your home address")]
    [Display(Name = "Home Address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

For the HTML or the view, here is the code where I link the model class.

```
@model ChoreBear_Website.Models.ViewModels.Signup;
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<form asp-action="Signup" class="login-inputs" asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly">
    <div>
        <input asp-for="Email" type="text" class="form-control email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required autofocus="true">
        <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input asp-for="Password" type="password" class="form-control password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required autofocus="true">
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Password"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input asp-for="ConfirmPassword" type="password" class="form-control password" name="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" required autofocus="true">
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="ConfirmPassword"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input asp-for="FirstName" type="name" class="form-control email" name="name" placeholder="John" required autofocus="true">
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="FirstName"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input asp-for="LastName" type="name" class="form-control email" name="name" placeholder="Lisbon" required autofocus="true">
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="LastName"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input asp-for="DateOfBirth" type="date" class="form-control email" name="dateofbirth" placeholder="1/1/1997" required autofocus="true">
        <span class="text-center" asp-validation-for="DateOfBirth"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input asp-for="PhoneNo" type="phone" class="form-control email" name="phone_number" placeholder="+60172845568" required autofocus="true">
        <span class="text-center" asp-validation-for="PhoneNo"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input asp-for="Address" type="text" class="form-control email" id="homeAddress" placeholder="5, South Ealing, London 65PT89, United Kingdom">
        <span class="text-center" asp-validation-for="Address"></span>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="Signup">Signup</button>
</form>
```

And finally, here is where I check if the "ModelState.IsValid()". This is in the controller class

```cs
[Route("signup")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Signup(Signup customerSignup)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Pass all the values which are arranged and store as "Customer" model to database.
        var registerUser = await _accountRepository.CreateCustomerAccountAsync(customerSignup);
        ModelState.Clear();

        //Check if the validation during registering the user has failed
        if(!registerUser.Succeeded)
        {
            foreach (var error in registerUser.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Description);
            }
        }
    }

    return View();
}
```

Now, I do run the project and every time I enter the values in the input box (they are not null), the validations kick in and prohibits me to creating new user. Every time I fill in everything single input which are hooked to the model class, the validations kicks in when the "Model" is not empty. Please advise, thanks!.

PS: I am programming in VS Code, so I do not know how to debugging like in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested it with a simple .net core MVC project. It seems that you've made a mess of "name" and "type" attribute values. The value of "name" attribute should match Signup model's corresponding attribute. The problematic fields are ConfirmPassword, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNo and homeAddress.

Also some of the "type" attributes are invalid( type="name" ). For example, it should be type="text" for that field. Similarly for the PhoneNo field it should be  type="tel". I also added a pattern for phone no validation. The pattern is "[+]{1}[0-9]{11,14}" as you can see in cshtml code.

After fixing these issues, I was able to see true in ModelState.IsValid attribute.

Here it is, the final edited version of your view :

```
 <div>
            <input asp-for="Email" type="text" class="form-control email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required autofocus="true">
            <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input asp-for="Password" type="password" class="form-control password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required autofocus="true">
            <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Password"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input asp-for="ConfirmPassword" type="password" class="form-control password" name="ConfirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" required autofocus="true">
            <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="ConfirmPassword"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input asp-for="FirstName" type="text" class="form-control FirstName" name="FirstName" placeholder="John" required autofocus="true">
            <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="FirstName"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input asp-for="LastName" type="text" class="form-control LastName" name="LastName" placeholder="Lisbon" required autofocus="true">
            <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="LastName"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input asp-for="DateOfBirth" type="date" class="form-control dateofbirth" name="dateofbirth" placeholder="1/1/1997" required autofocus="true">
            <span class="text-center" asp-validation-for="DateOfBirth"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input asp-for="PhoneNo" type="tel" class="form-control PhoneNo" name="PhoneNo" pattern="[+]{1}[0-9]{11,14}" placeholder="+60172845568" required autofocus="true">
            <span class="text-center" asp-validation-for="PhoneNo"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input asp-for="Address" type="text" class="form-control homeAddress" id="Address" placeholder="5, South Ealing, London 65PT89, United Kingdom">
            <span class="text-center" asp-validation-for="Address"></span>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hi @AntiqTech, thanks for your explanation. So basically, I still need inherit the name of the model properties and insert it into the "name" property in the Views? Correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @AntiqTech, it's working. Now I understand that the "name" property must match with model attribute name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the [Required] annotation on properties that you want to accept null and add '?' after the type if the properties are different of string in the Signup model so that the ModelState validation allows you to leave the field blank